# How to store callback methods?

Tags: python, methods, weak-references

i am trying to store some method callbacks but referring to it will keep the bound object alive, so i tried to keep a weakref to method but that doesn't seems to be possible?

so

- Why can't i keep a weak ref. to method (see example below)
- What is the best way to keep method ref? any thing in standard lib? Or I will have to keep function and object ref. separate?

example:

```
import weakref

class A(object):
    def m(self): pass

a = A()

import weakref

class A(object):
    def m(self): pass

a = A()

rm = weakref.ref(a.m)
print "is weak ref to method dead?",rm() is None
print "Q1. why can't i keep weakref to bound method?"

ra = weakref.ref(a)
m = a.m
print "delete object"
del a
print "is object dead?",ra() is None
print "delete method"
del m
print "is object dead?",ra() is None
print "Q2. hmmm so i am stuck i can't keep a ref as it stops the object from gc, but weakref to method isn't working?"
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply removing the object from the callback list to remove the reference?  Why not write a "disconnect" method that does `callback.remove(method)`?

Comment: yes that would be great to do, but still when I am storing a callback i would like if I can refer to it weakly, so that if someone forgets to disconnect, it automatically disconnects, wouldn't automating disconnect be a better idea?

Comment: What's wrong with a `with` block to assure disconnection?

Comment: nothing wrong with 'with' if it can be used in all cases, purpose of call back is that sometime in future in some event, some callback in some object will be called, how do I fit in a 'with' here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked [the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364923/how-to-connect-to-a-gobject-signal-in-python-without-it-keeping-a-reference-to-t)! In my question, I talk about GObject, but recognize it is a general problem in any kind of Python! I got help by lioro there, and what I use in my current code is below. Some important points:

- You can't weakref the method object. You have to weakref the instance and its function attribute, or simply the method name (as I do in my code below)
- You can add some mechanism to unregister the callback when your connected object goes away, if you don't do this, you will have the WeakCallback object live on instead, and exectute an empty method when the even occurs.

.

```
class WeakCallback (object):
    """A Weak Callback object that will keep a reference to
    the connecting object with weakref semantics.

    This allows object A to pass a callback method to object S,
    without object S keeping A alive.
    """
    def __init__(self, mcallback):
        """Create a new Weak Callback calling the method @mcallback"""
        obj = mcallback.im_self
        attr = mcallback.im_func.__name__
        self.wref = weakref.ref(obj, self.object_deleted)
        self.callback_attr = attr
        self.token = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.wref()
        if obj:
            attr = getattr(obj, self.callback_attr)
            attr(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.default_callback(*args, **kwargs)

    def default_callback(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Called instead of callback when expired"""
        pass

    def object_deleted(self, wref):
        """Called when callback expires"""
        pass
```

Usage notes:

```
# illustration how I typically use it
weak_call = WeakCallback(self._something_changed)
long_lived_object.connect("on_change", weak_call)
```

I use the `WeakCallback.token` attribute in subclasses I've made to manage disconnecting the callback when the connecter goes away

Comment: many other have pointer to similar solution, but I selected this one for being inpage

Answer (score 3):

Since the method is bound to the object, what would you expect to do with it if the object doesnt exist? What would self contain?

If you dont need the object in the method, make it a classmethod. Then your object will be GC:d even if you have a normal reference to the method.

Comment: but in this case object does exist, in the example I do not delete object till end

Comment: and I do want object, my simple way question is "is there a way to keep callbacks around , as weakref for objects, something like that

Answer (score 2):

Recipe 6.10 in Python Cookbook, "Keeping References to Bound Methods Without Inhibiting Garbage Collection", offers a pretty thorough though concise discussion and solutions.  You can read it online (on Google Books) [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=1Shx_VXS6ioC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=weak+reference+bound+method+cookbook&source=bl&ots=BB635E-cJ8&sig=0rGeqYoVImraEMVngx-9tFrBr3k&hl=en&ei=KqHxStS9B4SAswOds5j4AQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=&f=false); we give credit for that recipe to Knapka, Jolliton and Nicodemus (partly from the original activestate cookbook recipe that another answer already mentioned) though of course, as usual in the Cookbook, we (me, my wife Anna, and David Ascher) are the ones responsible for the overall flow of discussion and the exact code version chosen for printing, so, if something's wrong with those, it's *our* fault;-).

Comment: +1 for you answering :), btw why weakref.ref doesn't work for bound method?

Comment: @Anurag, it works as intended: it makes the reference to the bound method object weak! So, since there's no *strong* reference to that bound method object, said object immediately goes "poof" -- just as the discussion I already pointed to explains.

Answer (score 0):

They have a nice solution in:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81253/

Take a look at the last example, posted by Anonymous.